# Param which holds a boolean value is not getting updated when I click a link where the value is inverted

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, parameters

This is the sample url:
`/toggle/task/?id=64d2a447b84a449caad3e648&status=false`
The problem is that if the status is `true` it gets inverted but not the vice-versa

```
const Tasks = require('../models/toDoTasks');
module.exports.toggleTask = (req, res) => {
    (async () => {
        let taskId = req.query.id;
        let currentStatus = Boolean(req.query.status);
        await Tasks.updateOne(
            {_id: taskId}, {completed: !currentStatus}
        ).then(() => {
            return res.redirect('/');
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`);
        });
    })();
}
```

I have no clue right now for the reason this issue is happening

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `Boolean` to convert the query parameter since `Boolean('false')` will resolve to `true`.

Try with:

```
module.exports.toggleTask = (req, res) => {
    (async () => {
        try {
            let taskId = req.query.id;
            let currentStatus = req.query.status;
            await Tasks.updateOne(
                {_id: taskId}, {completed: currentStatus === 'false'}
            )
            return res.redirect('/');
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`);
        }
    })();
}
```

For more info read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean/Boolean#creating_boolean_objects_with_an_initial_value_of_false)